# Cannot connect to mysql server with remote access

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

My mysql server is installed in Ubuntu 16.04
I used `mysql -h 192.168.1.3 -u username -p` then following error shows

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.3'
>   (10061)

I tried to comment the bind-address, it didn't worked.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try `telnet 192.168.1.3 3306` first. If it fails: you may not on the same network and you cannot reach that IP from your network, there might be a firewall blocking that port, mysql is listening a different port or mysql is not running at all.

Answer (score 0):

`192.168.1.3` is local ip address, you might not be connected to same network. You need to access it through public ip address. You might also need to create one user and grant permission to that user to access it from outside.

Comment: I am in same local network. And I have added new user and granted persmission to them. But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Out of the box, MySQL will only allow access from the localhost address 127.0.0.1. To change this, you need to open the /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file and change the line:

bind-address = 127.0.0.1

to:

bind-address = 0.0.0.0

Save and close that file. Restart the MySQL server with the command:

systemctl restart mysql.service

here is the source : [solution](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-up-mysql-for-remote-access-on-ubuntu-server-16-04/)